# mistake in proof of theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I think proof for this theorem isn't true. I highlighted in red. A proper subgroup $ M $ is called an almost maximal subgroup of $ G $ if $ M $ is a maximal subgroup or $ \vert G : M \vert $ is a power of a prime number. In this proof said $ S_{4} $ has no cyclic supplement for every almost maximal subgroup of $ S_{4} $, while $ S_{4} = \langle (1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4) \rangle S_{3} $. I though mistake or this prof is mistake ?
[image]

Comment: @verret But authors said all these cases contradict the hypothesis that every almost maximal subgroup of $ H $ has a cyclic supplement in $ H $.

Comment: I think you are right and there is a mistake in this proof. But $C_3$ has no cyclic supplement in $S_4$, so you could replace $(S_4,S_3)$ by $(S_4,C_3)$, and then the proof would be correct.

Comment: @DerekHolt Why there is no element $ y \in S_{4} $ that $ S_{4} = \langle y \rangle C_{3} $ ? Since $ S_{4} $ has not cyclic subgroup of order $ 8 $ ?

Comment: Yes, that's right!